# Is GetTemplateChild Obsolete in .Net 3.5 and what is the difference between FrameWorkTemplate.FindName and ControlTemplate.FindName

Tags: c#, wpf, controltemplate

I overrided Template of a control in ResourceDictionary `Generic.xaml`. In that I added a button on which i wanted to add some events.

```
<Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
        --Added my button here.
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

So in Loaded event of control I did

```
Button  b = (Button)mycontrol.Template.FindName("PARTName", mycontrol)

//Add Events on my button
```

Some where on Internet I read that I can do

```
public override void OnApplyTemplate()
{
    base.OnApplyTemplate();

    UIElement editingelement = GetTemplateChild("PART_EditingElement");
    if (editingelement != null) 
    {
        // do something
    }
}
```

When I tried doing this suggestion for `GetTemplateChild` says Do Not Use.

[image]

So my question is

1. Why not to use `GetTemplateChild`. Is it obsolete? And
2. What is the difference between `FrameWorkTemplate.FindName` and `ControlTemplate.FindName`?

Comment: To answer your 2. question. `ControlTemplate` inherits `FrameworkTemplate` so the difference is properly nothing. Look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.controltemplate.aspx)

Comment: [Reason is found here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.gettemplatechild.aspx)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1.

The only difference is that `GetTemplateChild` will return `null` when:

- no template exists, or
- the named object exists but is not a `DependencyObject` (I don't know if this is even possible).

Otherwise, this code:

```
this.GetTemplateChild(name)
```

is literally equivalent to this code:

```
this.Template.FindName(name, this)
```

I don't know why it was marked "Do not use". I notice that this note existed on the MSDN page for [version 3](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.gettemplatechild%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and was removed from [version 3.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.gettemplatechild%28v=vs.90%29.aspx), but I don't know if that means anything.

2.

Did you mean `FrameworkElement`? Like Jens said, `ControlTemplate` inherits `FrameworkTemplate`, and they both use the `FrameworkTemplate.FindName` method. But [FrameworkTemplate.FindName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworktemplate.findname%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) and [FrameworkElement.FindName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.findname%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) are different. `FrameworkElement.FindName` only looks inside child elements but not the template, while `FrameworkTemplate.FindName` only looks at the template's own elements but not the parent element it's applied to.